# Is there a way to display an item that is being dismissed inside a dialog when using Dismissible widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating an app that is fetching people from repository and then it is displaying them on screen.
The user should be able to delete the person from the repository by swiping right. When the user swipes right `confirmDismiss:` property is fired up which pops up the dialog that asks the user if he is sure.

Is it possible for the `content:` inside a dialog to be that persons name. So if someone wanted to delete Nicolas Cage from the list, it would say "Are you sure that you want to delete Nicolas Cage?".

This is how the class Person is implemented:

```
class Person {

  int _id;
  String _fullName;
  String _email;
  String _mobile;
  String _other;

  Person(int id, String fullName, String email, String mobile, String other) {
    this._id = id;
    this._fullName = fullName;
    this._email = email;
    this._mobile = mobile;
    this._other = other;
  }
}
```

This is how the the Dismissible confirmDissmis is implemented:

```
confirmDismiss: (direction) async {
                          bool response = await showDialog<bool>(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                              return AlertDialog(
                                content: const Text('Are you sure you want to delete '),
                                actions: <Widget>[
                                  FlatButton(
                                    child: const Text('Yes'),
                                    onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, true),
                                  ),
                                  FlatButton(
                                    child: const Text('No'),
                                    onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              );
                            },
                          );
                        },
```

**In the AlertDialog content I want it to say "Are you sure you want to delete Nicolas Cage?" if we suppose that the user swiped right on the Nicolas Cage List Tile.** This method that I've tried doesn't work. It says Evaluation of this constant expression throws an exception, invalid constant value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter, how to use confirmDismiss in Dismissible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55777213/flutter-how-to-use-confirmdismiss-in-dismissible)

Comment: Not really. I know how to use confirmDismiss, what I don't know is how to show the Person full name field inside the Alert Dialog once the user swipes right.

Comment: simply append ``people[index].name`` with ``content: const Text('Are you sure you want to delete '),`` as ``content: const Text('Are you sure you want to delete ' + people[index].fullName),``

Comment: I had to remove const in front of Text widget also, because people[index].fullName isn't const. It worked for me! You solved my problem.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Kindly, if possible, mark my solution as accepted ✔ and upvote ⇧. Enjoy. I have added my answer below.

Comment: and kindly, ``do not edit your question with the solution`` once you get a solution !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply append `people[index].name` with `content: Text('Are you sure you want to delete ')` as `content: Text('Are you sure you want to delete ' + people[index].fullName)`.

**Code:**

```
confirmDismiss: (direction) async {
                          bool response = await showDialog<bool>(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                              return AlertDialog(
                                content: Text('Are you sure you want to delete the user: ${people[index].fullName}'),
                                actions: <Widget>[
                                  FlatButton(
                                    child: const Text('Yes'),
                                    onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, true),
                                  ),
                                  FlatButton(
                                    child: const Text('No'),
                                    onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              );
                            },
                          );
                        },
```